# Как получить результат с промежуточной таблицы в hibernate (Мапинг промежуточной таблицы в hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Есть процедура и после вызова процедуры я получаю результат с промежуточной таблицы. Как мне этот результат преобразовать в объект? Hibernate, обычный маппинг в POJO объект.
Как пример у меня есть процедура и в ней я получаю id, я хочу вывести эти id в POJO.

String userId;

String businessId;

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите про маппинг ХП у [Mkuong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/). Если хотите конкретного решения, предоставьте, пожалуйста, схему БД и нужную ХП.

Кроме того, можно воспользоваться Criteria или HQL, если ХП были выбраны только для того, чтобы делать сложные запросы. Если причина в чем-то еще (например, в желании улучшить производительность, доп контроле целостности итп), тогда ХП маппится через @NamedQuery.

Разумеется, в POJO маппится весь набор полей, а не только id.